# Missing noun in sentence using ほど

Tags: grammar, particle-ほど

> 動物王国のムツゴロウさんちの娘になってもいいと思うほど、動物好きなまる子だが、...
>   Maruko is a fan of animals to the extent that she thinks it's okay to become the daughter of *something to do with animal kingdoms and mud skippers*

Whilst I'm fascinated to know what 動物王国のムツゴロウさんち is all about, my primary question is about the structure of the sentence.

There seems to be a noun missing. If I had tried to put this in Japanese I would have written:

> ...ほど、まる子は動物がすきだが...
>   to the extent that ... Maruko likes animals

But the original sentence is

> to the extent that ... Maruko (who is an animal fan) is xxx?

where xxx is missing.

Is my alternative sentence correct? How can I understand the grammar of the original sentence?

Comment: すき vs. ずき  How are you reading the 好き part of the original?  That is crucial.  (I hope I am wrong, but I feel you are reading it as the former, aren't you?)  I so want to answer this question, but it is past my bed time.

Comment: @l'électeur I'm reading it as Xずき = fan of X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, who is 「動物王国{どうぶつおうこく}のムツゴロウさん」?  He is a very well-known and highly popular figure in Japan.  When the older half of the country hear the word "animals", they think of him.  I will just let Wiki explain below.  It even talks about what his 「動物王国」 is about.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masanori_Hata

Next, just a brief explanation of 「動物好{どうぶつず}きなまる子」.  For those unfamiliar, the 「好き」 part in this phrase, is read 「**ず**き」 and not 「**す**き」.

For reading comprehension, I recommend that one regard 「動物好きな」 as just an adjective meaning "***animal-loving***".  So, we have a "animal-loving Maruko" here.

I think many are already familiar with this, but 「～～さん**ち**」 means "~~'s home", "~~'s family", etc.  The 「ち」 comes from 「うち」.

Now, you called 「動物王国のムツゴロウさんちの娘になってもいいと思うほど、動物好きなまる子だが、...」 a sentence, but is it one?  ***Grammatically, no, because it lacks a predicate***.  If the author actually ended this with the "...", however, then it is an "honorary" sentence.  ***To make it as literal as possible***, it means:

> "It is Maruko who loves animals to the extent that she would not mind becoming the daughter of Mr. Mutsugoro of the Animal Kingdom."

The TL might sound awkward because I translated, as I said, a non-sentence that does not even have a predicate.

Even a one-step more literal translation would be:

> "Maruko who loves animals so much that she would not mind becoming the daughter of Mr. Mutsugoro of the Animal Kingdom, but ......"

There you could see what I mean by "non-sentence" and "no predicate".  It says nothing about what Maruko actually did.

In any case, you seem to have a good grip on the phrase in question.  It is a good sign that you felt something was missing.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is one of those times where it's hard to read this using our implicit biases as non-native Japanese speakers. If this were English it'd be an incomplete sentence, but this works in Japanese *because it works in Japanese*.

> 動物王国のムツゴロウさんちの娘になってもいいと思うほど、動物好きなまる子だが

If we wanted to simplify this sentence as much as possible, we could reduce it to

> まる子だが

Which is really just the author stating something about Maruko before continuing on to the rest of the sentence. If you think about it this way, the rest is a bit easier to parse.

> 動物王国のムツゴロウさんちの娘になってもいいと思うほど、動物好き

Such a fan of animals that she wouldn't mind becoming the daughter of a mudskipper = Maruko

The hard part about reading sentences like this is that it's constructed as what looks like a separate sentence, but it's closer to a string of dependent clauses tying into a larger idea. We do this in English as well, but we just switch the order around a bit

> Maruko, such a fan of animals that she wouldn't mind becoming the daughter of a mudskipper, XXX

Where XXX is the information that you perceived as missing in the Japanese version (it probably just comes after the chunk you quoted).